# How to make use of Maven Classifier in an application with Gradle build system

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Our application uses gradle build system with maven plugin and publishes the artifacts to an internal nexus repo. We are using puppet and mCollective to do the deployment. Its working as expected on our dev environment. Puppet pulls the artifact from snapshot repo and does the deployment.

Now, we are setting up test environment and we want to deploy from the same snapshot repo; so, we want to generate a unique artifact for test env which Puppet can pull from the repo and do the deployment. We are trying to leverage maven `classifier` to generate this artifact, but not sure how to specify this in gradle build script. Currently we have following in our gradle script for the artifact:

```
group = artifact_group_id // We read this from a properties file
version = artifact_version // We read this from a properties file
archivesBaseName = artifact_base_name // We read this from a properties file
```

Is there a way to provide `classifier` here? Please provide some inputs around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what kind of artifact you install and then deploy (`jar`, `war`), but but as you can see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) `jar` has `classifier` property. Have you tried setting it?

Comment: My apologies; the artifact I am generating is a WAR file.

Comment: `war` extends `jar` - classifier property is available as well.

Comment: I am going through the link you shared; even WAR also has a classifier property. I think this will work for me to generate artifacts with classifier.